# mongoose virtual field promise return value

Tags: mongoose, promise, field, virtual

I would like in my virtual field to return a value calculated in a promise:

```
CountrySchema
    .virtual('cityCounter')
    .get(function () {
        var counter;
        var id = this._id;
        City
            .count({ country: id })
            .then(function (count) {
                counter = count;
                console.log(id + ' ' + counter);

                return counter;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
    });
```

but nothing is returned. In the then promise, counter is correctly populated but I don't know how to retrieve the data in the get.

How to do it ? thank you.

Comment: You don't have a `return` in the `get`, but even then - the property would be a promise for the value and not hte value since virtuals are sync.

Comment: Ok thanks ! So how can I do ? methods?